# CXD5602のデータシートはどこから入手が出来ますか？

Tags: spresense, usb

CXD5602のnuttxのusb function deviceドライバが機能不足のために、新規に書き起こそうと考えています。
ただ、CX5602のマニュアルにはUSB機能についての詳細（レジスタの定義、挙動）などについて何も記載されていませんでした。
CXD5602については別途詳細なマニュアルが存在するのだと思うのですが、どこから入手が出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: 貴方の見た「CX5602のマニュアル」が何かを追記しておくと、回答者がそれを確認したりする手間が省けて良いでしょう。こちらですか？ [CXD5602 User Manual](https://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/products/common/pdf/CXD5602_user_manual.pdf)

Comment: ご指導ありがとうございます。
そうです。ご提示の資料を見ておりました。
この資料におけるUSBの機能については概略しか説明されておらず、どうしようもない状態です。

Answer (score 1):

確かに、User Manualは情報がほぼ無いですね。

ICそのものの話だから、ソニーに直接問い合わせたほうが良いかもしれません。

以下のページで、

https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/purchase-inquiries

> ビジネス連携に関するお問い合わせや、CXD5602/5247 を用いた製品の開発にご興味のあるお客様、製品に関するお困りごとについては、ソニーセミコンダクタソリューションズ（株）のお問い合わせフォームをお使いください。

と、ICのことで困ってたら、という文言があるので、こちらに問い合わせてみるしかないように思います。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。
リンクのボタンが「ビジネスに関するお問い合わせ」となっているので、ちょっと躊躇していましたが、一度問い合わせてみることにします。